# How to Put Formula Count another sheet in App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, app-inventor

my First ASK and last at 2020.
Im Newbie with google App Script, need some help
I had 2 Spreadsheet

1. Spreadsheet ssGETDATA  with SHEET1 column(`id,name,address,ts,visit`)
2. Spreadsheet ssVERIFY with SHEET1 column (`id,ts`)

I send data from Android use this code :

```
function doGet(e) {
 return message("Error: Please Try Again");
        }
  
function doPost(e) {
var id= e.parameters.id[0];
var name= e.parameters.name[0];
var address= e.parameters.address[0];
var visit= e.parameters.visit[0];
        
      var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
      sh.appendRow([id,name,address,ts,visit]);
      
      return message("Data Saved");
    } else {
      return message("Error: Please Try Again");
    }}}

function message(msg) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(msg);
}
```

I want to Verify data from ssGETDATA but data (`id`) appeared several times.
so my idea every time append row executed it put formula in column (visit)  with `=count(id,ssVERIFYSheet1!id)` to check it Verified or Not

how it applies in the google app script?

i hope when ssVERIFY changed then ssGETDATA column (`visit`) counting too.

thanks for your explanation. Happy new Year

Comment: This was solved on the App Inventor forum, introducing a formula to each row of the spreadsheet that did the comparison, using google apps script  https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/how-do-i-add-formula-countif-from-other-spreadsheet-when-appendrow/23487

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check if a column has a value probably is using `getValues()`, and search for the row in the array:

```js
const range = sheet.getRange('A2:A')
const hasBeenValidated = range.getValues()
  .flat()
  .some(value => value === id)

if (hasBeenValidated) {
 // [...]
}
```

Notice that I assumed that `id` is on column `A` and that it has a header.

`flat()` is necessary because `getValues()` returns a 2D array (array of rows) and we only need an array of values.

With this snippet you can check for existing entries at `ssGETDATA` and/or `ssVERIFY` before making any changes. It should work for any column but you may need to change the `value === id` part depending on the type of it (dates, for example).

### References

- [Range getValues() (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Array.prototype.flat() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [Array.prototype.some() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [SpreadsheetApp openByUrl(url) (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)